# Bayesian updating and information cascades

Tags: bayesian, social-network

Suppose that a group of $N = 100$ people is asked to choose between two different options, $A$ and $B$. Every member of the group is not sure whether $A$ is better than $B$ or vice versa, but each member possesses some information that allows to guess a probability, $p$, that $A$ is better than $B$. So that if $p > 0.5$ the member will choose $A$, otherwise he will choose $B$.

However, they do not deliberate independently: if the first member will explicit his choice relying only on his prior, the following members will update their information (prior) with the decisions explicited by previous members (likelihood), and then they will explicit their decision using the updated information (posterior).

In this way, the last members who speak will be heavily influenced by previous decisions.

Does this mean that **in similar contexts** with bayesian updating we can have information cascades? In particular, the last members of the group in a certain sense stop using their information, since they rely on the decisions of the previous members?

Comment: This seems to be more a question about group dynamics than about probability.  Maybe try  http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/      or   http://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, it is exactly about social networks dynamics... I was trying to draw a connection between SN and bayesian thinking

Comment: The information supplied by the first declaration of preference is uncalibrated for the second person, as it encodes nothing more than p<0.5 or >0.5. In contrast, the second person's prior information yields a more precise probability. That means that the second person cannot perform a Bayesian updating. I would say that the setup does not allow proper Bayesian treatment at all.